# Changing file permissions in kernel

Tags: c, linux, file-permissions, kernel-module

I am writing kernel module(C in Linux) and I want to change the permission of the other files in it.
any solution?
since I am in kernel I can't use chmod syscall and ...
thanks for your help

This is my Makefile:

```
> obj-m += ca.o
> 
>     all:
>       make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
>     
>     clean:
>       make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

And this is my Code:

```
> #include <linux/string.h>
> #include <linux/mm.h>
> /* Snip, tons of includes (all of them :))*/
> #include <linux/delay.h> .... int procfile_write(struct file *file,
> const char *buffer, unsigned long
> count,
>          void *data) { ...    sys_chmod(path, per); ... } ...
```

When Making it gives a warning:

> `WARNING: "sys_chmod" [file] undefiened`

and when loading the module with "sudo insmod" it gives this error:

> `Unknown sybol in module`

it seems that this error happens especialy in kernel modules. any idea? again thanks!

Comment: What files are you trying to change the permissions of?  In the kernel module?

Comment: Normal files. Like the ones in home or etc..
the only point is that my code is in Kernel.

Comment: Ummm, I gotta hear the "why" for this one. You can do this from userspace, so why are you doing it in the kernel?

Comment: @derobert - Sometimes, ignorance is bliss ;)

Comment: well I was going to make a kernel module that does many things like this one. I always like to learn more :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syscalls are not exported symbols. You need to do a little bit of hacking if you want them.

you want to get your fingers on `sys_call_table`. It contains a pointer to every syscall.
Look at `arch/x86/kernel/syscall_table_32.S` or `arch/i386/kernel/entry.S` on older kernels.

You can `grep sys_call_table /usr/src/linux/System.map` (or `/proc/kallsyms` if the symbols are exported) to find the base address of this table.
You can have this address as a parameter for your module (converting an hex string to a pointer will be needed).

You'll be able to call the right syscall with the offset defined in `arch/x86/include/asm/unistd_32.h` (or `include/asm-i386/unistd.h` on older kernels).
You get something like: `#define __NR_chmod               15`

Macros are helpful:

```
#define DO_SYSCALL_2(sc, t1, a1, t2, a2)                       \
    (((asmlinkage long (*)(t1, t2)) sys_call_table[__NR_##sc]) (a1, a2));
#define USER_SYSCALL_2(sc, t1, a1, t2, a2)                     \
    static inline asmlinkage long syscall_##sc(t1 a1, t2 a2)   \
    { return DO_SYSCALL_2(sc, t1, a1, t2, a2) }

USER_SYSCALL_2(chmod, const char __user *, filename, mode_t, mode);
int my_code(void) { return syscall_chmod(arg1, arg2); }
```

Also, if you are passing kernel buffer (for filename for examples) that are supposed to be user buffers, don't forget to change the data segment:

```
mm_segment_t oldfs = get_fs(); set_fs(KERNEL_DS);
ret = syscall_XXX(...);
set_fs(oldfd);
```

Comment: +1 (wish I could +4) excellent answer Pafy. I nominate this for the correct answer in-place of my own 'guess'

Comment: wow! thanks! I will try it as soon as possible! it seems so nice:-D

Comment: :)
And also, you can hijack them (just replace the right pointer in the syscall table with a function of your own). And if you save the original pointer, you have a wrapper :)

Answer (score 5):

**Welcome to stackoverflow!** IIRC you want `sys_chmod()`

> **From the Linux Kernel Mailing List**
>
> On Thu, Feb 20, 2003 at 11:10:27PM +0100, Andrea Arcangeli wrote:
>   On Thu, Feb 20, 2003 at 12:40:43PM -0500, Jeff Garzik wrote:
>
> > On Thu, Feb 20, 2003 at 11:04:37PM +0530, Prasad wrote:
> >
> > > Is there a way using which i could invoke a syscall in the kernel
> > >       space? The syscall is to be run disguised as another process. The actual
> >
> > Call sys_whatever(). Look at the kernel code for examples.
> >
> > The kernel already does this in
> >     various places. sys_read, sys_write,
> >     open_filp, sys_close, and other
> >     functions are safe to call from kernel
> >     code -- though this is discouraged.
> >     init/do_mounts.c is a particularly
> >     annoying case, and is a big reason why
> >     klibc needs to be merged. syscalls
> >     should be made from userspace, not the
> >     kernel.

People are starting to worry, as this isn't the kind of thing you might do in the kernel (unless you are use you know what you are doing). If you just want to change permissions on a certain event, do it from userspace with [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) or similar.

Disclaimer aside:

Here is some code I found in another kernel module, which uses the sys_* calls:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/fcntl.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>
#include <linux/string.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
/* Snip */

int openflags = O_WRONLY|O_CREAT;
if (ml != 1)
        openflags |= O_TRUNC;
wfd = sys_open(collected, openflags, mode);

if (wfd >= 0) {
    sys_fchown(wfd, uid, gid);
    sys_fchmod(wfd, mode);
    state = CopyFile;
}
```

Also found:

```
asmlinkage long sys_rename(const char __user *oldname, const char __user *newname);
asmlinkage long sys_chmod(const char __user *filename, mode_t mode);
asmlinkage long sys_fchmod(unsigned int fd, mode_t mode);
```

in `include/linux/syscalls.h`

Mind you, it has been a while since I did any kernel stuff. **Check** that this is the appropriate interface for chmod stuff and that you arn't shortcutting any other call that might implement security hooks, for example.

Also, **[This link contains information on syscalls](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/KernelAnalysis-HOWTO-3.html)** and their symbols. Also **[Here](http://www.digilife.be/quickreferences/QRC/LINUX%20System%20Call%20Quick%20Reference.pdf)** is a quick-reference of user-space API system calls and where they are implemented in the kernel.

Comment: thanks! it compiled with sys_chmod and gave a WARNING: "sys_chmod is not defiened". 
and when loading by "sudo insmod ..." gave ERROR: "unknown symbol in module"
I had included all header files including syscalls, sys and 40 others.

Comment: http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.30.5/include/linux/syscalls.h#L428
http://www.gelato.unsw.edu.au/lxr/ident?i=sys_chmod
Those might help.

Comment: Also, see edit. I added the includes from the source snippet (which was the source of initramfs)

Comment: Also check your linker stuff such as "-L/linux-2.6.x/..." in your Makefile/GCC

Comment: really really thanks for the time you put on it! but it still has warning and error. I put the details on the edit.

Comment: Looks like your compilation process is broken, not your source. You will need to ask another question :) Also see edit at the top of my post.